# GORM model foreign key to different Postgres schema

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have 2 separate Go APIs that connect to the same Postgres database into different schemas. Each user has all access to all schemas.

- In the first API I have the `User` model with `schema1.Users` table
- In the 2nd I have the `Task` model with `schema2.Tasks` table

```
type User struct {
 gorm.Model
}

type Task struct {
 gorm.Model
 CreatedBy uint
 User User `gorm:"foreignKey:CreatedBy;references:User"`
}
```

When I try to run the 2nd API, the migrations create a Users table in schema2 and connects the foreign key there.

If I use the line below I get an error

```
 User User `gorm:"foreignKey:CreatedBy;references:schema1.User"`
```

```
[error] invalid field found for struct github.com/xyz/models.Tasks's field User: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface
```

Any ideas how to connect the different schemas?

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @nerdizzle No, we ended up using one schema and we use db role permissions to restrict the separate APIs to use the other ones tables. Both can use the common tables.