# gorm different schema relation for tables

Tags: postgresql, go, database-schema, go-gorm

To further explain my problem I have a database in postgreSQL. With the intent of the database to look cleaner I split most of the tables in between two schema-s one for the "users" and a second for the so called "teams". As it's expected I've created a many to one relation between the teams.team table and the users.user table by giving the teamID inside the user table. I'm writing the backend for the current software in GoLang and decided to use Gorm as way to handle the database. I've gotten somewhat the hang of gorm and figured out how to use schema-s and to test that Gorm can handle my database solution I decided with the structures, I've created to represent the tables, to create again all my tables in the db.
For the different schema-s I've had to make different connections and specify that I want them for the specific schema and since I have to write that there's a connection to Team inside User it thinks it's in the same schema

```golang
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    FirstName string
    LastName  string

    Email      string
    ElsysEmail string
    Mobile     string

    Password string

    InfoID     uint
    Info       Info
    SecurityID uint
    Security   Security
    RoleID     uint
    Role       Role
    TeamID     uint
    Team       Team

    LastLogin time.Time
}
```

For anyone having a problem with creating tables inside a schema here's my solution:

```golang
dsn := "host=localhost user=postgres password=password dbname=ht9 port=5432 sslmode=disable"
db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{NamingStrategy{TablePrefix: "schemaName."}})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

disclaimer : my problem is almost identical to this one - [GORM model foreign key to different Postgres schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72898859/gorm-model-foreign-key-to-different-postgres-schema) - but no one's answered it yet

Answer (score 0):

Try `implementing the Tabler interface.` as follow

```
type AppUser struct {
    global.GVA_MODEL
    Username string `json:"userName" gorm:"index;comment:user'sname"`
}


func (u *AppUser) TableName() string {
    return "app.app_users"
}
```